# Use sed to make sure a bash variable always ends with a % sign

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am writing a hobby `bash` script (in process of learning `sed` command). I have wrote a function which takes zero or one argument and call `pactl` command with the last argument always ending with a `%` sign. The pactl command controls the speakers of my `ubuntu machine`. I can change volume using it and even increase it beyond `100%`. For example, to set volume to 150%, I use:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 150%
```

The function that I have wrote with just arguments check:

```
function increase {
    if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then
        pactl set-sink-volume $@
    elif [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
        pactl set-sink-volume 0 $1%
    fi
}
```

Now, if a user pass only one argument, I want to make sure there is only one `%` sign at the end in the argument. So, I just want to extract the number using `sed` and explicitly add the % sign at the end of the number.

I have tried following combination but they are not working:

```
echo "150%" | sed -n 's/\([^%]*\)%?/\1/p'

echo "150%" | sed -n 's/\([^%]*\)%/\1/p'

echo "150%" | sed -n 's/\(\d+\)/\1/p'

echo "150%" | sed -n 's/\(\d+\)%/\1/p'

echo "150%" | sed -n 's/\(\d+\)%?/\1/p'
```

By "not working", I mean when I try to pass both 150 and 150% (echo "150" and echo "150%" at different times), it doesn't give the right result at one or the other time.

Comment: No idea but FYI very few UNIX tools (none of the standard ones) would recognize `\d` as meaning "digit". Always use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the numeric part, append `%` in the replacement. E.g:

```
sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\{1,\}\)%*/\1%/p'
```

With GNU sed it can be shortened to:

```
sed -En 's/^([0-9]+)%*/\1%/p'
```

---

I'd prefer bash's regex matching mechanism over sed to validate and sanitize such an argument though.

Comment: What was wrong in my implementation? I know I wasn't appending % in my replacement string but it should have extracted atleast the numeric part of the expression.

Comment: @abhiarora By default sed uses [Basic Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03); which doesn't support `?`, `+` and `\d`

Comment: And this one *`echo "150%" | sed -n 's/\([^%]*\)%/\1/p'`* works, it extracts the number

Comment: but these doesn't `echo "150" | sed -n 's/\([^%]*\)%/\1/p'` and `echo "150%%" | sed -n 's/\([^%]*\)%/\1/p'`

Comment: @abhiarora Yep. The first one tries to match a `%` after number, but there is no `%` in input. Wrt the second, it matches `150%`, and replaces it with `150`; it doesn't touch the extra `%` at the end.

Comment: Why `\d` doesn't work but `[0-9]` works in `sed -En`. Any reason?

Comment: `\d` is not a part of [POSIX Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html). Implementations may or may not provide that extension, seems like the one you use don't

Comment: I am not sure why my question has been downvoted! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

If I got your question correctly could you please try following.

```
echo "150%" | sed 's/\([^%]*\)%.*/\1/'
```

It will give output as `150`. Now if we run with `echo "150"` as follows:

```
echo "150" | sed 's/\([^%]*\)%.*/\1/'
```

Output will be still `150`

OR in case you want to have `%` too in output use(after seeing @oguz ismail's answer adding this):

```
echo "150%" | sed 's/\([^%]*\)%.*/\1%/'
```

OR

```
echo "150" | sed 's/\([^%]*\)%.*/\1%/'
```

***Explanation of `sed` command:*** Following is the explanation of `sed` command it is only for explanation purposes.

```
echo "150%" |      ##echoing 150% and using pipe(|) sending its standard output as input to sed command.
sed '              ##Starting sed command from here.
s                  ##Using s option for using substitution.
/\([^%]*\)%.*      ##Using memory buffer capability by taking everything before 1st occurrence of % and save it into (...) escaping \( and \) to remove its special meaning. Then mentioning % and everything else.
/\1/               ##Now mentioning \1  means substitute complete Line with only matched 1st memory buffer value.
'
```

---

---

***With `awk` answer: If you are ok with `awk` answer:***

```
echo "150%" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="%"} {print $1,""}'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your answer is that you use '\d' and sed doesn't offer that regex extension. You can use Posix character classes though, so you can do something like:

`echo "150%%" | sed -E 's/^([^[:digit:]]*)([[:digit:]]+)(.*$)/\2%/'`

Answer (score 1):

You got the sed answer you were looking for but FYI you wouldn't actually use sed for a job like this, just a shell subsitution:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function increase {
    if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then
        echo pactl set-sink-volume "$@"
    elif [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo pactl set-sink-volume 0 "${1%\%}%"
    fi
}

increase "$@"

$ ./tst.sh 3 4
pactl set-sink-volume 3 4

$ ./tst.sh 150
pactl set-sink-volume 0 150%

$ ./tst.sh 150%
pactl set-sink-volume 0 150%
```

Comment: That's really something I don't know. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GNU sed, you can do it so:

```
echo "150%" | sed -nr 's/([[:digit:]]+).?/\1/p'
150

echo "150%" | sed -nr 's/([[:digit:]]+).?/\1%/p'
150%
```

Option "-r" for extended regular expression (no need to use "\" frequently)